# Different CodePush options for Staging/Prod

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

In order to serve updates faster to testers, I would like to use different CodePush options for Staging and Production. For example, in Staging distributions, I would like to remove `minimumBackgroundDuration` from the config below

```js
let codePushOptions = {
  checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
  installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME,
  minimumBackgroundDuration: 60 * 10,
};
const CodePushApp = codePush(codePushOptions)(App);
```

What strategies are there to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your CodePush integration as Production and Staging with using
`sync` function.

Check below example:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";

const CodePushService = ({ stagingKey, productionKey, testUser }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    codePush.notifyAppReady().then(() => {
      if (testUser) {
        codePush.sync({
          deploymentKey: stagingKey,
          installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
          updateDialog: {
            appendReleaseDescription: true,
            descriptionPrefix: "\n\nDeveloper Notes:\n\n",
          },
        });
      } else {
        codePush.sync({
          deploymentKey: productionKey,
          rollbackRetryOptions: {
            delayInHours: 1, // default is 24
            maxRetryAttempts: 3, // default is 1
          },
        });
      }
    });
  }, [testUser, productionKey, stagingKey]);

  return null;
};

export default codePush({ checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL })(
  CodePushService
);
```

You can use the above code like below:

```js
import CodePushService from './CodePushService';

const App = () => {
  return(
    <>
      <CodePushService
        stagingKey="xxxxxxxxxxx"
        productionKey="xxxxxxxxxx"
        testUser={true} // make this part dynamic
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this code?